# where is"multiselect-selected-text" class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm using [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) drop down list. When i inspect the generated HTML elements in the browser, it has the following HTML generated for the Button.

```html
<button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="" style="width: 200px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">
        <span class="multiselect-selected-text"></span> 
        <b class="caret"></b>
</button>
```

the span element has class "multiselect-selected-text", however i don's see that class has been defined in any CSS. I searched the whole solution. The only reference i found was in bootstrap-multiselect.js at line no 320 and 1277
I have the following files
      jquery-1.11.2.js
      bootstrap-multiselect.js
      bootstrap.css v3.0.0
      bootstrap-multiselect.css

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an [independent plugin](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect), the definition would be inside the CSS file provided with the package.

Comment: As i mentioned I have the css file from that plugin  included in the project.. however that CSS class is not in that file.

Comment: I assume you want to find it in order to edit the CSS. In that case, just add a new definition in your last CSS file for that class and add which ever properties you like.